# scroll to top is not smooth enough

Tags: jquery

i am using this script for scroll to top button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".upp").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1200);
    });
});
```

It is going to top while being animated, but the animation is not smooth enough.it jumps at some parts, then slides to top. I even tried increasing the value from 1200 to 5000, but it scrolls while jumping at certain points. i am using simple jquery library (latest version).Do you think that adding jquery UI will solve anything? please help.

Comment: Always felt comfortable with [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) ^^

Comment: Could you re-create the jumping effect in a fiddle ?

Comment: Is `.upp` an `a` element? If so, try this: `$(".upp").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1200); });`

Comment: @moonwave99 Don't scrollTo plugin use scrollTop animation internally?

Comment: You may find some help here...thought it would be helpful for you...http://gazpo.com/2012/02/scrolltop/

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to utilize the `easing` option of `.animate()`

[From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> **Easing**
>
> > The remaining parameter of `.animate()` is a string naming an easing function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called `swing`, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called `linear`. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the [jQuery UI suite](http://jqueryui.com/).

```
$(".upp").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1200, 'linear');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an easing or animation problem.**

The smoothness is going to depend on your content. That's it.

If you have image heavy site, scrolling will be a pain. Image backgrounds... Don't even think about many high quality fixed image backgrounds and smooth scroll... Browsers don't handle that well.

The only workaround I found was to scrap scroll completely and implement a fake one myself by changing the margin of my container. With CSS3 transitions that is generally smooth even for heavy sites. But this is generally not worth the hassle...

**Update**

If it's still slow after stripping your the images, then the problem clearly sits in your parallax code. Look at the bottlenecks. Find out which frames cause the delays. See if you can optimize the code a bit. Less references to DOM? Maybe cache some elements? Simplify some maths?

Comment: you are quite right ZorleQ, as my site is heavy on background images..its a parallax site with moving big images. Please give me some idea on how it can be done by css3

Comment: but just now i did something...i renamed the image directory so no images are being called. it means that the scroll should now work fine, but its working EXACTLY THE SAME

Comment: "Exactly the same" or "equally bad, but slightly better"? I think you've just answered your own question here. Parallax done right is amazing - http://journey.lifeofpimovie.com/ but it's so easy to get it all wrong - http://www.tridentpp.com/case-studies/ . I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.docs').offset().top}, 2000);
```

Comment: Why have you posted a second answer? You can just edit your original response.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS3 transition:  {original DEMO site:http://mitgux.com/demo/smooth-scroll-to-top-using-css3-animations/index.php }

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8NGL/1/)

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").css({
      "margin-top": -$(this).offset().top+"px",
      "overflow-y": "scroll", // This property is posed for fix the blink of the window width change 
    });
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    $("body").css("transition", "margin-top 1.2s ease");
    $("body").css("margin-top", "0");
    $("body").on("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function () {
        // Remove the transition property
        $("body").css("transition", "none");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

```
//*** Scroll to Top *** use with less *** use with html ***
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
            $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);    // Fade in the arrow
        } else {
            $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);   // Else fade out the arrow
        }
    });
  
    $('#return-to-top').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('html, body').offset().top,
        },'linear');
    });//End Scroll to Top
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help you to do the smooth scroll:

```
$('a').click(function() {

    //For testing moving the scroller to the top
    $('div').scrollTop(0);

    //Scroll to bottom
    $('div').animate({scrollTop: $('div').get(0).scrollHeight}, 3000);

   //Prevent Default
   return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/GjXzD/

Comment: This doesn't constitute an answer. Post your solution here for others to read.

Comment: It's better to add `.stop()` before animate otherwise the scrollbar will get stuck at the end if you press the button again while the animation didn't finish

Comment: i have tried all these solutions, but apart from a little difference through this: $(".upp").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 3200, 'linear');
}); i have not been able to get the smooth scroll